# Mostrar a maior média dentre todas as médias calculadas

Tags: java

Criei um algoritmo para calcular a média de um surfista, mas ele pode pegar quantas ondar quiser se ele quiser parar o algoritmo tem que apresentar a maior média dessas calculadas e passar para o segundo surfista. Alguém sabe como eu conserto isso?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class trabalhosurf {
  public static void main(String[]args) {
   int cod;
   double juiz1,juiz2,juiz3,juiz4,juiz5,soma,media1,media2,menor,maior,surfista1,surfista2,mediafinal1,mediafinal2;
   Scanner ler=new Scanner(System.in);
   do {

       System.out.println("Informe a nota do juiz 1 para o surfista 1");
    juiz1 = ler.nextDouble();
    menor = juiz1;
    maior = juiz1;
    System.out.println("Informe a nota do juiz 2 para o surfista 1");
    juiz2 = ler.nextDouble();
    if (juiz2<menor) {
     menor = juiz2;
     if (juiz2>maior) {
     maior=juiz2;
     }
    }
    System.out.println("Informe a nota do juiz 3 para o surfista 1");
    juiz3 = ler.nextDouble();
    if (juiz3<menor) {
     menor=juiz3;
     if(juiz3>maior) {
     maior=juiz3;
     }
    }
    System.out.println("Informe a nota do juiz 4 para o surfista 1");
    juiz4 = ler.nextDouble();
    if (juiz4<menor) {
      menor=juiz4;
      if (juiz4>maior) {
      maior=juiz4; 
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Informe a nota do juiz 5 para o surfista 1");
    juiz5 = ler.nextDouble();
    if (juiz5<menor) {
     menor=juiz5;
     if (juiz5>maior) {
     maior=juiz5; 
    }
    }
    soma = juiz1+juiz2+juiz3+juiz4+juiz5 - menor - maior;
    media1= soma/3;
    mediafinal1=media1;
    if
    (mediafinal1>media1);{
    mediafinal1=media1;
    }    
    System.out.println("Media da onda do surfista 1 :"+ mediafinal1);
    System.out.println("Deseja repetir o calculo da media do surfista 1?");
    System.out.println("1)sim");
    System.out.println("2)nao");
    cod=ler.nextInt();


   }while(cod!=2);
   System.out.println("Nota final do sufista 1 é " + mediafinal1 ); 
    int codl;

    do {
       System.out.println("Informe a nota do juiz 1 para o surfista 2");
    juiz1 = ler.nextDouble();
    menor = juiz1;
    maior = juiz1;
    System.out.println("Informe a nota do juiz 2 para o surfista 2");
    juiz2 = ler.nextDouble();
    if (juiz2<menor) {
     menor = juiz2;
     if (juiz2>maior) {
     maior=juiz2;
     }
    } 
    System.out.println("Informe a nota do juiz 3 para o surfista 2");
    juiz3 = ler.nextDouble();
    if (juiz3<menor) {
     menor=juiz3;
     if(juiz3>maior) {
     maior=juiz3;
     }
    }
    System.out.println("Informe a nota do juiz 4 para o surfista 2");
    juiz4 = ler.nextDouble();
    if (juiz4<menor) {
      menor=juiz4;
      if (juiz4>maior) {
      maior=juiz4; 
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Informe a nota do juiz 5 para o surfista 2");
    juiz5 = ler.nextDouble();
    if (juiz5<menor) {
     menor=juiz5;
     if (juiz5>maior) {
     maior=juiz5; 
    }
    }
    soma = juiz1+juiz2+juiz3+juiz4+juiz5 - menor - maior;
    media2 = (soma)/3;
    System.out.println("Media da onda do surfista 2 :"+ media2);
    System.out.println("Deseja calcular uma nova media para o surfista 2 ?");
    System.out.println("1)sim");
    System.out.println("2)nao");
    System.out.println("Nota final do sufista 2 é " + media2 ); 
    codl=ler.nextInt(); 
   }while(codl!=2);
    double campeao;



    {
    if (media1>media2) {
   campeao=media1;  
   System.out.println("O vencedor é surfista 1 com nota: "+ campeao);
    }else if (media1<media2){
   campeao=media2;  
   System.out.println("O vencedor é surfista 2 com nota: "+ campeao);
    }else if(media1==media2){
     System.out.println("empatados");
    } 


  }

 }
}
```

Comment: Consertar o que?

Answer (score 1):

O seu principal problema é isso:

```
if (juiz3<menor) {
 menor=juiz3;
 if(juiz3>maior) {
 maior=juiz3;
 }
}
```

O que você queria é isso:

```
if (juiz3 < menor) {
    menor = juiz3;
}
if (juiz3 > maior) {
    maior = juiz3;
}
```

Ou seja, era para colocar um `if` depois do outro, e não um dentro do outro.

O seu código tem um monte de duplicações, o que é muito ruim. Veja o código abaixo que as elimina. Os comentários explicam o que o código faz:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TrabalhoSurf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numeroJuizes = 5;
        int numeroSurfistas = 2;

        // Faz tudo isso uma vez para cada surfista.
        for (int surfista = 1; surfista <= numeroSurfistas; surfista++) {

            // Faz quantas vezes forem necessárias enquanto o usuário quiser repetir o cálculo da nota deste surfista.
            s: while (true) {

                // Utilizado para armazenar as notas dos juízes.
                double[] notas = new double[numeroJuizes];

                // Lê as notas dos juízes.
                for (int juiz = 1; juiz <= numeroJuizes; juiz++) {
                    System.out.println("Informe a nota do juiz " + juiz + " para o surfista " + surfista + ".");
                    notas[juiz - 1] = Double.parseDouble(ler.nextLine());
                }

                // Obtém a maior e a menor nota e também a soma das notas.
                double maior = notas[0];
                double menor = notas[0];
                double soma = notas[0];
                for (int juiz = 2; juiz <= numeroJuizes; juiz++) {
                     double nota = notas[juiz - 1];
                     if (nota > maior) maior = nota;
                     if (nota < menor) menor = nota;
                     soma += nota;
                }

                // Calcula a média, descartando a maior e a menor nota.
                double media = (soma - maior - menor) / (numeroJuizes - 2);

                // Mostra a média.
                System.out.println("Media da onda do surfista " + surfista + ": " + media);

                // Prende o usuário num loop até o usuário responder 1 ou 2.
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Deseja repetir o calculo da media do surfista " + surfista + "?");
                    System.out.println("1) Sim");
                    System.out.println("2) Nao");

                    // Lê a opção escolhida pelo usuário.
                    String escolha = ler.readLine();

                    if ("1".equals(escolha)) continue s; // Refaz com o mesmo surfista.
                    if ("2".equals(escolha)) break s; // Vai para o próximo surfista, se houver.

                    // Mostra a mensagem de erro. O while garante que o programa insiste.
                    System.out.println("Desculpe, não entendi a sua escolha. Tente novamente.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Enfim, o segredo é você sempre procurar eliminar código copiado-e-colado. Use arrays para guardar sequências de números que tenham algum significado ao invés de criam um monte de variáveis de propósito parecido.

Answer (score 0):

Se bem entendi o q vc quer é só criar uma variável lá `double maior_media` dai atribui:

```
if(media > maior_media) maior_media = media;
```

Imprime este quando necessário e lembre de zerar a variável antes da próxima interação.